# Where do I enter in the Stack Overflow API key?

Tags: discussion

Where do I need to enter the Stack Overflow API key to grant more API requests?

I've just received one for my application that makes several API requests.

Comment: For future reference, the [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/) Q&A site is intended for questions about the API.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the higher quota for your application, specify your API key using the `key` parameter in the API request.

For example, instead of requesting [`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/4689?site=stackoverflow`](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/4689?site=stackoverflow), I would add my key and request [`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/4689?site=stackoverflow&key=6XCcTC6F0uxg2NYxjQSxSA((`](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/4689?site=stackoverflow&key=6XCcTC6F0uxg2NYxjQSxSA(() instead.

If your application is being used by individual users (not just autonomously), you can get a separate increased quota *for each user* if they go through [the full `access_token` authentication flow](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).